# nginx | site is not available by accessing with www

Tags: nginx, configuration

May be you can help me. I'm using nginx and ubunty and my site is not available by typing: **www.example.com**. And available as: **example.com**.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    ...
```

Where is a problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if 'www.example.com' refers to your site. If not, you have to create an 'A' record for this. In most situations you have to do this at the company who is providing your DNS management, probably the one where you registered your domain.